# Blender Render: Python material

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

How do I use python to set keyframes for the diffuse colour of materials in blender render. This is what I got, but it doesn't work.

```
mat = bpy.data.materials("Abc")
mat.diffuse_color = (1.0,0.0,0.0)
mat.keyframe_insert("default_value", frame=scene.frame_current)
```

I have an existing material that I want to set keyframes for, but I don't know how to do it. I tried searching it up and only saw python scripts for cycles materials.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what I did wrong. The documentation of materials on the blender api page did not mention "get", but the bpy_struct said you can use "get" in the function, so:

```
mat = bpy.data.materials("Abc")
```

Should be:

```
mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Abc")
```

Also I have to define what scene of scene.frame_current is.
That means at the beginning, I need to import bpy.

```
import bpy
scene = bpy.context.scene
```

Also default_value is nonsense to be placed there. Being the diffuse color that's had its keyframe changed, it should be:

```
mat.keyframe_insert(data_path="diffuse_color", frame=scene.frame_current)
```

In conclusion, it should look like this:

```
import bpy
scene = bpy.context.scene

mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Abc")
mat.diffuse_color = (1.0,0.0,0.0)
mat.keyframe_insert(data_path="diffuse_color", frame=scene.frame_current)
```

Comment: You don't have to use `get()` the material name is a dictionary key so you can use `mat = bpy.data.materials["Abc"]`

Comment: oh. I didn't know that. Are they the same though?

Comment: The beauty of get is `collection.get("doesnt exist")` returns `None` whereas `collection["doesn't exist"]` will return an error.  IMO ` if mat is not None:` is more elegant than a try except clause, or if `"doesnt exist" in collection`, hence I use `get(...)` as a matter of practice.

Comment: ah! then im fine here.